# Defining sub-structure of sub-class inside parent class

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, declaration, inner-classes, definition

Consider the following snippet of code:

```
class MyClass
{
private:
    struct PrivateClass
    {
        struct SubStruct;
    };

public:
    struct PrivateClass::SubStruct {};

private:
    PrivateClass::SubStruct member;
};
```

MSVC and gcc compile this code without any errors. clang, however, produces the following error:

```
<source>:10:26: error: non-friend class member 'SubStruct' cannot have a qualified name
    struct PrivateClass::SubStruct {};
```

So, who's right? Is this a clang bug?

Comment: If this is a bug in any compiler(s), it would be great if you could file bug(s) for them. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standard (latest draft) says:

> [class.nest]
>
> If class X is defined in a namespace scope, a nested class Y may be declared in class X and later defined in the definition of class X or be later defined in a namespace scope enclosing the definition of class X.

In this example, the class `SubStruct` that is declared in the class `PrivateClass` is defined in neither later in `PrivateClass` nor later in a namespace scope (but rather, later in a class scope of the outer `MyClass`). Nor is `PrivateClass` itself defined in a namespace scope.

Unless there is another rule allowing this, the definition of the sub-nested class as in the example is not at least explicitly allowed. Clang seems to be correct.

Answer (score 5):

According to [`[class]/11`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class#11) in the C++ 17 Standard:

> **If a class-head-name contains a nested-name-specifier**, the
>   class-specifier shall refer to a class that was previously declared
>   directly in the class or namespace to which the nested-name-specifier
>   refers, or in an element of the inline namespace set (10.3.1) of that
>   namespace (i.e., not merely inherited or introduced by a
>   using-declaration), **and the class-specifier shall appear in a
>   namespace enclosing the previous declaration.** In such cases, the
>   nested-name-specifier of the class-head-name of the definition shall
>   not begin with a decltype-specifier.

So it seems the clang compiler is right.